How to compute the volume integral for the potential of an arbitrary point outside a uniformly charged ball?
$$\frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\iiint_{D}^{}\frac{1}{\left\| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \right \| }dV'$$

$D$ is a ball of radius $R$
$\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector of the point where we want to calculate the potential
$\mathbf{r'}$ is the position vector of the parametrisation of the ball

When
$$\mathbf{r}=z\hat{\bf{z}}$$
$$ \Rightarrow \left\| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \right \|^2=z^2+r'^2-2r'z\cos\vartheta'$$
the integral can be computed using spherical coordinates since
$$\int\frac{r'^2\sin\vartheta'}{\sqrt{r'^2+z^2-2r'z\cos\vartheta'}}d\vartheta'=\frac{r'\sqrt{r'^2+z^2-2r'z\cos\vartheta'}}{z}$$
David J. Griffiths on Introduction to Electrodynamics states that when
$$\mathbf{r}=x\hat{\bf{x}}+y\hat{\bf{y}}+z\hat{\bf{z}}$$
$$ \Rightarrow \left\| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \right \|^2=r'^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-2r'(x\sin\vartheta' \cos\varphi' + y\sin\vartheta' \sin\varphi' + z\cos\vartheta')$$
the integral should have the same value - by symmetry - since we can rotate the system and align the point with the $z$ axis but I cannot figure a way to compute it as is or make a suitable substitution (maybe in terms of three-dimensional rotation).
$$\int\frac{r'^2\sin\vartheta'}{\sqrt{r'^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-2r'(x\sin\vartheta' \cos\varphi' + y\sin\vartheta' \sin\varphi' + z\cos\vartheta')}}d\vartheta'=\ ??$$

please use \sin, \cos instead of simply sin and cos

@K.defaoite Done :-)

@Sebastiano thanks!

The question is taken from this textbook? David J. Griffiths-Introduction to Electrodynamics-Addison-Wesley (2012)

@Sebastiano this is the textbook I am working on, yes, but I found nothing besides the argument that we can rotate everything so that the point lies in the z axis which is pretty vague to me.

I studied that book a few years ago although I am a high school teacher in Mathematics and Physics. You have my approvation.

@Sebastiano nice to hear, I will add a reference to the book.

See here: https://www.numerade.com/ask/question/texts-answer-problem-228-be-thorough-by-showing-all-steps-needed-and-explaining-each-step-comprehensively-problem-228-use-eq-229-to-calculate-the-potential-inside-a-uniformly-charged-solid-s-34873/ I think that this is your problem.

To mathematicians, the word sphere refers to a surface. I think you mean to say that $D$ is a ball or — at least — solid sphere. I would also use $\mathbf r$ for the variable point in the ball (since you’re writing $dV$ and not $dV’$).

@TedShifrin sure, I will edit.

I’m confused. The spherical coordinates approach is right. You did the $\theta$ integral, and then put in $R$, which I do not understand. $z$ here is a constant. I do not understand what follows with that mess afterwards.

@TedShifrin $R$ should be $r$ and the second $\theta$ integral is what I get when $\mathbf{r}$ is as stated. I will add he calculation of $\left| \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \right |$ for the second integral.

But we’ve assumed that — by symmetry — the fixed point is $(0,0,z)$. And you’re integrating on $\theta\in [0,\pi]$.

@TedShifrin for the second integral $\mathbf{r}=x\hat{\bf{x}}+y\hat{\bf{y}}+z\hat{\bf{z}}$

Why? You don’t want that mess.

@TedShifrin I want to show this for an arbitrary point outside the ball.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

$\textbf{Hint:}$ The easiest way to do this would be change your coordinate system to shift the center of the sphere from the origin to $\mathbf{r}$. This gives a new integral
$$\frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\iiint_{B(\mathbf{r},R)}\frac{dV'}{||\mathbf{r}'||}$$
Then there are two cases, for when $|\mathbf{r}|\equiv r$ is greater than or less than $R$. To get you started on the greater than case, convert the equations to spherical coordinates
$$||\mathbf{r}||^2-2\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}'+||\mathbf{r}'||^2=R^2$$
$$\implies r^2-R^2+r'^2=2rr'\cos\theta'$$
by choosing to align $\mathbf{r}$ along the $z'$ axis which we are free to do. The easiest way to set up the integral is with $d\theta'$ first
$$\frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r-R}^{r+R}\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2-R^2+r'^2}{2rr'}\right)}r'\sin\theta'\:d\theta' \:dr'\:d\varphi'$$
$$= \frac{\rho}{2\epsilon_0}\int_{r-R}^{r+R}r'-\frac{(r^2-R^2)}{2r}-\frac{r'^2}{2r}\:dr'$$
Can you finish this computation, and compute the limits for the $r<R$ case?

I am confused, why is this not the same as aligning $\mathbf{r}$ along the z axis in the first place?

@giannisl9 look at the domain of integration. It is not the same as $D$. Translating it allows us to have a simpler integrand instead of the mess of square roots you originally had.

I can see that but aligning $\mathbf{r}$ with the z' axis seems the same to me as choosing a point on the z axis in the first place.

@giannisl9 but you also didn't translate. You left your ball centered at the origin.

I am just looking for a proof where no such arguments are present. If we are free to choose $\mathbf{r}$ to align wherever we want, we should be able to prove this for the general case, no?

@giannisl9 you aren't making any sense. Did you or did you not learn how to do $u$-substitutions? Is that not a tool in your toolbox?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I see now that choosing $\mathbf{r}$ to align with the z' axis has to do with setting up the spherical coordinates after the shift which is fine.

Please remove the part about the two cases since the question is about the potential at a point outside the ball so I can accept this answer.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\iiint_{D}{1 \over \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}}\dd V'\ \color{black}{\mbox{where}}\ D\ \color{black}{\mbox{is a ball of radius}}\ R}:\ {\LARGE ?}
\end{align}
Because $\ds{\vec{r}}$ is a $\ds{given\ vector}$, I can choose $\ds{\vec{r}}$ along the $\ds{z\mbox{-}axis}$. At the end of the whole calculation, I can restore the general characteristic of $\ds{\vec{r}}$. Namely,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\iiint_{D}{1 \over \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}}\dd V'} =
{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\iiint_{D}{\,r'^{2}\,
\dd r'\ \dd\Omega_{\,\vec{\,r}\,'} \over \root{r_{>}^{2} -2r_{>}r_{<}\cos\pars{\theta\,'} + r_{<}^{2}}}
\\[2mm] & \ \mbox{where}\quad {r_{<} \atop r_{>}} =
{\min \atop \max}\braces{r,r'}\mbox{. Therefore,}
\\[5mm] & \color{#44f}{{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\iiint_{D}{1 \over \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}}\dd V'}
\\[5mm] = & \
{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{R}{\,r'^{2}\sin\pars{\theta'}\,\dd r'\,\dd\theta\,'\dd\phi' \over
r_{>}\root{1 -2\pars{r_{<}/r_{>}}\cos\pars{\theta\,'} + \pars{r_{<}/r_{>}}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\, 2\pi\int_{0}^{R}r'^{2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\,\,\dd x\, \over
r_{>}\root{1 -2\pars{r_{<}/r_{>}}x + \pars{r_{<}/r_{>}}^{2}}}
\dd r'
\\[5mm] = & \
{\rho \over 2\epsilon_{0}}
\int_{0}^{R}r'^{2}\int_{-1}^{1}
{1 \over r_{>}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{r_{<} \over r_{>}}^{\ell}\on{P}_{\ell\,}\pars{x}\,\dd x\,\dd r'
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{P}_{\ell}}$ is a $\ds{Legendre\ Polynomial}$. Then,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{{\rho \over 4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\iiint_{D}{1 \over \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}}\dd V'}
\\ = & \
{\rho \over 2\epsilon_{0}}\int_{0}^{R}r'^{2}
{1 \over r_{>}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{r_{<} \over r_{>}}^{\ell}\
\overbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}\on{P}_{\ell\,}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{2\delta_{\ell 0}}}\ \,\dd r'
\\[5mm] = & \
{\rho \over \epsilon_{0}}\int_{0}^{R}r'^{2}\
{1 \over r_{>}}\,\dd r'
\\[5mm] = & \ \left\{\begin{array}{rclc}
\ds{{\rho \over \epsilon_{0}}\pars{%
\int_{0}^{r}{r'^{2} \over r}\dd r' +
\int_{r}^{R}{r'^{2} \over r'}\dd r'}} & \ds{=}
& \ds{\color{#44f}{{\rho \over 6\epsilon_{0}}\pars{3R^{2} - r^{2}}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r < R}
\\[2mm]
\ds{{\rho \over \epsilon_{0}}
\int_{0}^{R}{r'^{2} \over r}\dd r'} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\color{#44f}{{\rho \over 3\epsilon_{0}}{R^{3} \over r}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{r > R}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

(+1) for the complete answer.

For an independent check, the integral formulas are solutions to the following problem: find the spherically symmetric, diffenrtiably  continuous solution of
$$\mathbf d \star \mathbf d \Phi =\cases{0 \quad |\mathbf x|\gt R\\ \rho  \quad\ |\mathbf x| \le R}$$
for a piecewise continuous charge distribution.
For a function of radial coordinate $r$, independent of the spherical angles, the metric Laplacian $\Delta$-term has the form $$\mathbf \Delta=\mathbf d \star \mathbf d  = \frac{1}{\text{dvol}} \nabla_r^+ \ \text{dvol} \ \nabla_r =  \frac{1}{h_r h_\theta h_ \phi}\partial_r \frac{1}{h_r}\ \ h_r h_\theta h_\phi \frac{1}{h_r}\partial_r$$ with the three metric  scale factors $h_k dx_k$ for the coordinate differentials. Only the two $r$ scale factors of the angles $r d \theta,r \sin \theta d \phi$ survive:
$$\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r \left( r^2 `\Phi'(r)\right)=\cases{0,\quad r\gt R\\ \rho , \quad\ r\le R}$$
The general external solution is $$r^2 \Phi'(r) = c'_1, \quad \Phi(r)= \frac{c_1}{r}+ c_2$$
The value $c_2$ at $r=\infty$ can be set to zero (gauge invariance).
The internal solution is
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\ (r^2 \Phi')' = \rho,  \quad (r^2 \Phi')' =\rho \ r^2, \quad r^2 \Phi' = \frac{\rho \ r^3}{3} + c'_3,  \quad \Phi = \frac{\rho  r^2}{6} +\frac{c_3}{r}+c_4$$
In the internal solution $c_3$ represents a finite point charge at $r=0$, can be set to zero
At $r=R$ both solutions have to be coincide differentiably continuously (continuity of the normal electric field in absence of a surface charge distribution)
$$c_4+\frac{\rho  R^2}{6}=\frac{c_1}{R} , \quad \frac{\rho  R}{3}=-\frac{c_1}{R^2}$$
$$c_1 = -\frac{1}{3} \ \rho \  R^3 ,\quad c_4 =-\frac{1}{2}  \ \rho \  R^2$$
$$\Phi(r)=\cases{ \rho \ \left(\frac{r^2}{6} - \frac{R^2}{2}\right)  \quad r<R \\
-\rho \frac{R^3}{3}}$$
